# I am working on codeIgniter when i copy my project server to local it not loads local it redirect to localhost/dashboard

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

codeIgniter version 2.2.6 which my project is running on server and php version 7.3 on my local
but the issue is that when i runing the project on local from `c/xampp/htdocs`
through localhost/testsite it redirect to `http://localhost/dashboard/` page

this is my `.htacess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.testsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.testsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and this is `index.php` file

```
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
            //error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'development':
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

and this is my `application/config/config.php` file

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=="localhost") {
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/public_html';
    $config['index_page'] = '';
}elseif  ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=="uat.icwdc.com") {
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://uat.icwdc.com/testsite';
    $config['index_page'] = '';
}else {
    $config['base_url'] = 'https://www.testsite.com';
    $config['index_page'] = '';
}
```

Comment: May be you have redirect it via some Controller with some condition.

Comment: No i checked this i think that only mistake is that what i am wrong doing in .htacess file and index.php